# I want to be able to schedule a shutdown and restart of a VM on azure using Powershell

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, scheduled-tasks, auto

I have a VM machine that i would like to shutdown/power off at a certain time and then restart at a certain time. I have tried this in task scheduler and obviously i can shutdown at a given time but cant then set the restart time

I would like the VM machine to shutdown at 10pm and restart at 5am and run a task scheduler task i have that restarts key services (that side of it works)

I have played around with automation tasks within azure but run into a variety of RMLogin issues

i just want the simplest way to schedule this

Answer (score 0):

there is no auto-startup as far as I'm aware, so you'd have to use some sort of Automation. There is an [official solution from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management). Which is somewhat overkill, but should work (never tried it, tbh). There are various other scripts online that work with Azure Automation. They are easily searchable ([like so](https://www.google.com/search?q=azure+vm+start+stop+runbook&oq=azure+vm+start+stop+runbook&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.3276j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

If you go to my blog you can also find an example script that does the same, and an example of a runbook that you can trigger manually to start\stop vms

Answer (score -1):

I would assume you would have gone through the below mentioned suggestion, The automation book https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management is the way to achieve this. You can achieve auto shutdown via the portal but not restart and start.

Please check this links that talks about Start and Shut down role of the VM through REST API. You can wire up the end point with Azure Function, Puppet, or Chef to automate this process

VM - Start/Shut down Role(s): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/jj157189(v=azure.100)

If anything doesn't work for you I would suggest to leave your feedback.
So to simply answer your question, no, there is not a more simple way to achieve this.

If you want, you can add your feedback for this feature suggestion here
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback

Comment: VM - Start/Shut down feature pricing. I have checked in portal but it not much clear. Can you please explain any how much they charge if I set VM auto Shutdown and Start weekly once?